# TypeError after trying to plot dataframe with mpf.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mpf

I have a panda dataframe with the following columns:
[image]

Now I would like to plot out a chart with mpf.plot. But I am getting the following error:
[image]

How can I avoid the above TypeError Message?
I did set the df index with the following command:

```
dfnew_plot = dfnew_plot.set_index('Date')
```

Comment: Are you sure Date is already a datetime column? in other words, when you print ```type(dfnew_plot.index)``` does it return ```pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex``` ?

Comment: Result is pandas.core.indexes.base.Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index isn't the correct dtype. It needs to be converted using:

```
dfnew_plot.index = pd.to_datetime(dfnew_plot.index)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your solution solves my problem. Question: If I print the df before and after the code dfnew_plot.index = pd.to_datetime(dfnew_plot.index), i do not see any differences? What do I have to learn, to understand the difference?

Comment: Your index was a dtype of string or "object" according to pandas. To check the dtype of any Series (column, or index) you can use the dtype attribute. Example: `dfnew_plot.index.dtype'. If the result is "O" or "Object" or anything besides "DateTimeIndex" then your financial plotting library won't work.